# why does i get non-nullable error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am developing a flutter project, but I get this error and I don't know how to solve

[image: Here is the error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to update your flutter sdk in `pubspec.yaml` to:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'
```

Comment: I upgraded, now I am getting a lot of errors like (A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'String') any idea??

Comment: You can follow https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide and which will help migrate your code to null safety